# Is it ok to share only blog links on answer rather than its detail - Someone doing it

Tags: discussion

Is the guy named `Ahsan Horani` promoting his blog or just helping everyone?

Here are the links for his answers.

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298345/80212
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298343/80212
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298341/80212
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298347/80212
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298340/49772

Please clarify, I only share few of his answer

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Great. Welcome :)

Comment: In the future, you should raise a flag and explain the self-promotion in the flag text box.